# TikzEdt fonts in a tree

Tags: tikz-pgf, fontsize, tikz-styles, tikz-trees

I'm trying to represent some matrices in a tree. The higher the node of a matrix, the large I want the font to be (and the lower the node, the smaller the font).
I came up (in TikzEdt) with

```
begin{tikzpicture} [
  level 1/.style={level distance=3cm,sibling distance =10cm},
  level 2/.style={level distance=3cm,sibling distance =1.5cm},
  level 3/.style={level distance=1.5cm,sibling distance =0.8cm},
  every node/.style = {shape=rectangle, rounded corners, draw, align=center}
    ]

  \node {\Huge1 0 0\\\Huge 0 1 0\\\Huge0 0 1} 
    child { node {\LARGE1 0 0\\\LARGE1 1 0\\\LARGE1 1 1} 
       child { node {\Large1 0 0\\\Large2 1 0\\\Large3 2 1}  } 
    child { node {1 0 0\\2 0 1\\3 1 2}  }
       child { node {0 1 0\\1 2 0\\2 3 1}  }
       child { node {0 0 1\\1 0 2\\2 1 3}  }
       child { node {0 1 0\\0 2 1\\1 3 2}   }
       child { node [font=\fontsize{140}{120}\selectfont] {0 0 1\\0 1 2\\1 2 3}  }
  }      ;
\end{tikzpicture}
```

which gives

[image: matrix tree with decreasing fonts]

As one can see \Huge, \LARGE and \Large work, apart from the baselineskip, but I want to choose the fonts myself, which I tried in the  last matrix. As one can see, the baselineskip {120} works, but the fontsize {140} has not the desired effect.

My TikzEdt preambule is

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,amsmath, amssymb,bm,color}
\usepackage[margin=0cm,nohead]{geometry}
\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
%\usepackage{tikz-qtree}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{anyfontsize}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows,arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,graph}
%\usetikzlibrary{graphdrawing,graphdrawing.trees}
\usepackage{relsize}
```

My last solution is

```
\begin{document}

\begin{forest}
  matrices,
  scale fonts=from 45pt to 15pt,
  [1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1,l sep=1cm
    [1&0&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&1
     [1&0&0\\2&1&0\\3&2&1]
     [1&0&0\\2&0&1\\3&1&2]
     [0&1&0\\1&2&0\\2&3&1]
     [0&0&1\\1&0&2\\2&1&3]
     [0&1&0\\0&2&1\\1&3&2]
     [0&0&1\\0&1&2\\1&2&3]    
    ]
    [1&0&0\\1&0&1\\1&1&1 ,l*=3.5
     [1&0&0\\2&1&1\\3&2&1]
     [1&0&0\\2&1&1\\3&1&2]
     [0&1&0\\1&2&1\\2&3&1]
     [0&0&1\\1&1&2\\2&1&3]
     [0&1&0\\1&2&1\\1&3&2]
     [0&0&1\\1&1&2\\1&2&3]    
    ]
    [0&1&0\\1&1&0\\1&1&1 ,l*=6
     [1&1&0\\2&1&0\\3&2&1]
     [1&0&1\\2&0&1\\3&1&2]
     [1&1&0\\1&2&0\\2&3&1]
     [1&0&1\\1&0&2\\2&1&3]
     [0&1&1\\0&2&1\\1&3&2]
     [0&1&1\\0&1&2\\1&2&3]    
    ]
    [0&0&1\\1&0&1\\1&1&1  ,l*=6
     [1&1&1\\2&1&1\\3&2&1]
     [1&1&1\\2&1&1\\3&1&2]
     [1&1&1\\1&2&1\\2&3&1]
     [1&1&1\\1&1&2\\2&1&3]
     [1&1&1\\1&2&1\\1&3&2]
     [1&1&1\\1&1&2\\1&2&3]    
    ]
    [0&1&0\\0&1&1\\1&1&1 ,l*=3.5
     [1&1&0\\2&2&1\\3&2&1]
     [1&0&1\\2&1&2\\3&1&2]
     [1&1&0\\2&2&1\\2&3&1]
     [1&0&1\\2&1&2\\2&1&3]
     [0&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&3&2]
     [0&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&2&3]    
    ]
    [0&0&1\\0&1&1\\1&1&1
     [1&1&1\\2&2&1\\3&2&1]
     [1&1&1\\2&1&2\\3&1&2]
     [1&1&1\\2&2&1\\2&3&1]
     [1&1&1\\2&1&2\\2&1&3]
     [1&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&3&2]
     [1&1&1\\1&2&2\\1&2&3]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}  
\end{document}
```

which gives[image]

Comment: Welcome! You aren't using the code in a comparable place, are you? That is, you're not saying e.g. `font=\Huge` in the first case. Do you see the same difference if you compare equivalent cases?

Comment: OK, this is already a large improvement: 
  \node [font=\Huge]{1 0 0\\0 1 0\\0 0 1}
    child { node [font=\LARGE] {1 0 0\\1 1 0\\1 1 1} 
       child { node font=\Large] {1 0 0\\2 1 0\\3 2 1}  }

Comment: If you add `\usepackage{lmodern}` (improved replacement for the cm fonts), you get fully scalable fonts and `\fontsize` works as expected. Allthough that node is not properly adjusted then (and I don't know how to fix this).

Comment: While it's fine (although not necessary) to add your solution to your question, a better way of showing this is to Accept (and upvote) @cfr 's answer by clicking on the green checkmark beside the voting arrows.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution using `forest`. (I don't know what TikZEdt is.)

This attaches a particular font size to a particular level of the tree. I've also created a command to simplify the input of your matrices: input a comma delimited list of triples and it turns them into a matrix.

```
\mfmt{100,010,111}
```

Here's a full example.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\newcommand*{\enormous}{\fontsize{40}{40}\selectfont}
\forestset{node fonts/.style={
   for tree={draw,rounded corners,inner sep=.2em},
   where level=0{font=\enormous}
      {if level=1{font=\large}
         {if level=2{font=\normalsize}
            {if level=3{font=\tiny}
               {font=\footnotesize}}}}}}

    \newcounter{rowcount}
\newcommand*{\addrow}[1]{%
    \stepcounter{rowcount}%
    \ifnum\value{rowcount}<3\scan{#1}\\%
    \else\scan{#1}\fi}
\newcommand{\mfmt}[1]
   {\setcounter{rowcount}{0}%
   \forcsvlist\addrow{#1}%
   \vspace*{-.5ex}}

% This code adapted from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/233227/2693
\newcommand*\scan[1]{\scanA#1\end}
\newcommand*\scanA[1]{\ifx\end#1\else
   \ifx#1,\relax\else%
   \space#1\space% <- The processing over one token is here
   \fi
   \expandafter \scanA \fi
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}node fonts
[\mfmt{100,010,001} [\mfmt{001,010,111} ] [\mfmt{001,010,111} ] [\mfmt{001,010,111} ] [\mfmt{010,111,000} [\mfmt{000,111,010} ] [\mfmt{000,111,010} [\mfmt{000,111,010} ] [\mfmt{000,111,010} ] [\mfmt{000,111,010} ] ] [\mfmt{000,111,010} ]]]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: output of code]

Comment: (+1) The scanning stuff is very neat-looking indeed. But possibly an excessive nesting of `tabular`s? Effectively, you're putting a `tabular` in another `tabular` here because `linguistics` does `align=center`, if I remember correctly.

Comment: And, obviously, I can't condone the choice of `lmodern` :-).

Comment: @cfr I wrapped things in `\tabular` because of the extra \\ in the last row. But since I have a negative `vspace` anyway, I could just replace that with a larger value.

Comment: Yes, but you could just define a different format so you don't get the default `tabular` as well as yours. That is, define `content format` so that you control the `tabular` and aren't putting a `tabular` inside another `tabular` cell.

Comment: @cfr I just got rid of the `tabular` entirely.  I'm still not clear why I need a negative `vspace` at all.

Comment: What do you do if you want a double-digit number in a cell of the matrix?

Comment: @cfr You don't. :) Then you'd need a different input schema anyway, since there's no way to tell how to parse a 4 digit string without an overt delimiter.

Comment: TikzEdt is simply an editor: http://www.tikzedt.org. BTW, I think it's an excelent `tikz` editor but, unfortunately, it's no more mantained :(

Answer (score 1):

Here's another Forest version which scales the fonts in each level proportionately. `matrices` enables the style `matrix` for the tree. `matrix` wraps the content in a `smallmatrix` environment. `scale fonts=from <dimension at root> to <dimension at greatest level>` scales the fonts between the two given dimensions. For example, `scale fonts=from 40pt to 10pt` will make the root use `40pt`, leaves in the last level use `10pt` and all other nodes use something appropriate in between. Obviously, this requires a scalable font.

The advantage of this is that you can add to or reduce the number of levels and the scaling will adjust automatically, but you still have complete control over the smallest and largest fonts in the tree.

If you use a font package such as `lmodern` (pah!), remove the `\tlstyle` from the definition else you'll get an error.

Note that you really don't need a special macro to wrap a `tabular`, `array` or similar environment around node contents. Forest already includes this functionality. (Indeed, it is used every time you say `align=<something>`.)

The following is a much-mangled adaption of [Alan Munn's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/384007/).

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\forestset{
  matrices/.style={
    for tree={
      matrix,
      draw,
      rounded corners,
    },
  },
  matrix/.style={
    content format={%
      \ensuremath{\noexpand\begin{smallmatrix}\forestoption{content}\noexpand\end{smallmatrix}}%
    },
  },
  declare count register={total levels},
  declare dimen register={level incr},
  level incr'=0pt,
  total levels'=0,
  scale fonts/.style args={from #1 to #2}{
    before typesetting nodes={
      total levels/.max={>O{level}}{tree},
      level incr/.process={Rn+dw2+n+d{total levels}{#2-#1}{##2/##1}},
      for tree={
        font/.process={ORw2+nw+dw{level}{level incr}{##1*##2}{##1+#1}{\tlstyle\fontsize{##1}{##1}\selectfont}}
      },
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  matrices,
  scale fonts=from 40pt to 10pt,
  [1&0&0\\0&1&0\\0&0&1
    [0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&1]
    [0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&1]
    [0&0&1\\0&1&0\\1&1&1]
    [0&1&0\\1&1&1\\0&0&0
      [0&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&0]
      [0&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&0
        [0&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&0]
        [0&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&0]
        [0&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&0]
      ]
      [0&0&0\\1&1&1\\0&1&0]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

[image: scaling fonts]

## EDIT

Here's a version which uses the comma-split method from Alan's answer, but implements it in Forest.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{cfr-lm}
\usepackage[linguistics]{forest}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\forestset{
  matrices/.style={
    for tree={
      matrix,
      draw,
      rounded corners,
    },
  },
  matrix/.style={
    content format={%
      \ensuremath{\noexpand\begin{smallmatrix}\forestoption{content}\noexpand\end{smallmatrix}}%
    },
  },
  declare count register={total levels},
  declare dimen register={level incr},
  level incr'=0pt,
  total levels'=0,
  scale fonts/.style args={from #1 to #2}{
    before typesetting nodes={
      total levels/.max={>O{level}}{tree},
      level incr/.process={Rn+dw2+n+d{total levels}{#2-#1}{##2/##1}},
      for tree={
        font/.process={ORw2+nw+dw{level}{level incr}{##1*##2}{##1+#1}{\tlstyle\fontsize{##1}{##1}\selectfont}}
      },
    },
  },
  add row/.style={
    if rows={}{rows=#1}{rows+=\\#1}
  },
  declare autowrapped toks={rows}{},
  auto matrices/.style={
    matrices,
    before typesetting nodes={
      for tree={
        split option={content}{,}{add row},
        content/.option=rows,
      },
    },
  },
}

\begin{document}
\begin{forest}
  auto matrices,
  scale fonts=from 40pt to 10pt,
  [{1&0&0,0&1&0,0&0&1}
    [{0&0&1,0&1&0,1&1&1}]
    [{0&0&1,0&1&0,1&1&1}]
    [{0&0&1,0&1&0,1&1&1}]
    [{0&1&0,1&1&1,0&0&0}
      [{0&0&0,1&1&1,0&1&0}]
      [{0&0&0,1&1&1,0&1&0}
        [{0&0&0,1&1&1,0&1&0}]
        [{0&0&0,1&1&1,0&1&0}]
        [{0&0&0,1&1&1,0&1&0}]
      ]
      [{0&0&0,1&1&1,0&1&0}]
    ]
  ]
\end{forest}
\end{document}
```

The output is as above.

Comment: @AlanMunn You don't need `etoolbox` to split the rows. See above. But splitting within the rows is different. I don't see a nice way to do this without an explicit marker, unless you only ever want single digits in your matrices.

Comment: Very cool! I had no idea about the `split option`.

Comment: Well, that's quite some coding to digest. Will come back to it later. Thnx anyhow.

Comment: I am realy impressed what you guys came up with, but it is (quite) a bit over my head, since I'm not a (La)Tex programmer and have no intention to become one. The first solution I liked most, but understood the least, so I'll stick to the second one. In my answer I'll show how I simplified it.