# Problems with StrSubstitute from xstring and hyperref

Tags: hyperref, xstring

I am trying to define a label from a string with blanks to use with hyperref. But I get an error. The example below does not compile if the two lines with comments are uncommented. Is there a remedy for this?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{color}
\usepackage{hyperref}

\def\animal{zebra with stripes}
\def\mylabel{\StrSubstitute{\animal}{ }{}}
\def\thelabel{zebrawithstripes}

\begin{document}
\hypertarget{\thelabel}{\noindent Here is a zebra.} \\
Go to \hyperlink{\thelabel}{\textcolor{blue}{\animal}}.\\

%\hypertarget{\mylabel}{\noindent Here is a zebra.} \\
%Go to \hyperlink{\mylabel}{\textcolor{blue}{\animal}}.\\

\mylabel

\end{document}
```

Comment: \mylabel my look like "zebrawithstripes" but it actually consists of `\let \@xs@assign \@xs@expand@and@assign \@xs@StrSubstitute@zebra with stripes`

Comment: Ok. Can I turn it into "zebrawithstripes"?

Comment: Possibly, but not using StrSubstitue.  Also, you can us \animal as a hypertarget label.  You don't need to remove the spaces.

Comment: Ah! That's great news. (I thought an earlier error came from using spaces in the label, but I was apparently wrong.)

Comment: If you still want to remove spaces, you might look at https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing

Comment: @Rasmus: Why do you want to remove the spaces?

Comment: I don't any longer. As I wrote above, I thought the spaces caused an error in hyperlink, but I was wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The non-expandable macros of package `xstring` have usually a tailing optional argument for a command that will contain the result:

```
\StrSubstitute{\animal}{ }{}[\mylabel]
```