# In what ways can one write a parser in plain TeX or packageless LaTeX?

Tags: plain-tex, documentclass-writing, parsing, minimal

I want to write my own document class as a literate program with as minimal of a dependency tree as possible as an exercise to test my ability.

I've implemented a stable foreach loop by shredding an argument, but similarly attempting to parse a calendar failed.

```
\def\@pointer{\@pointer}
\long\def\@iterate#1#2#3,{
    \def\cell{#3}
    \ifx\cell\@pointer
        \let\next=\relax
    \else
        \def#1{#3}
        #2
        \def\next{\@iterate{#1}{#2}}
    \fi
    \next
}
\long\gdef\foreach#1in#2#3%
{\@iterate{#1}{#3}#2,\@pointer,}

\def\@testOccidental#1 #2, #3{
    \def\subject{#1}
    \foreach \month in {January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,October,September,November,December}{
        \ifx\subject\month
            #1 #2, #3 (Occidental Solar)
        \fi
    }
}
\def\checkCalendar#1{
    \def\subject{#1}
    \@testOccidental\subject
}

\checkCalendar{\today}
```

Comment: `\@testOccidental` is defined with three arguments, you only pass one.

Comment: what do you mean by "in what ways can you write a parser"? xmltex for example implements an xml parser using no packages (or even  latex format) commands it just uses tex primitives so it can be loaded in initex with no preloaded format.

Comment: you are missing lots of `%` your iterate loop will insert several spaces at each iteration.

Comment: See `listofitems.tex` as a plain-TeX package input, for nested parsing tools.  https://ctan.org/pkg/listofitems

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1|37.1904

Answer (score 5):

The question title asks an unanswerable question about how (in general) to write a parser, but restricting to the code posted

```
\catcode`\@=11

\def\@pointer{\@pointer}
\long\def\@iterate#1#2#3,{
    \def\cell{#3}
    \ifx\cell\@pointer
        \let\next=\relax
    \else
        \def#1{#3}
        #2
        \def\next{\@iterate{#1}{#2}}
    \fi
    \next
}



\long\gdef\foreach#1in#2#3%
{\@iterate{#1}{#3}#2,\@pointer,}

X\foreach \z in {a,b,c,d}{[\z]}X

\bye
```

The loop works but adds a lot of space to the output

[image]

Removing the space tokens from the definition prodces

[image]

```
\catcode`\@=11

\def\@pointer{\@pointer}
\long\def\@iterate#1#2#3,{%
    \def\cell{#3}%
    \ifx\cell\@pointer
        \let\next=\relax
    \else
        \def#1{#3}%
        #2%
        \def\next{\@iterate{#1}{#2}}%
    \fi
    \next
}



\long\gdef\foreach#1in#2#3%
{\@iterate{#1}{#3}#2,\@pointer,}

X\foreach \z in {a,b,c,d}{[\z]}X

\bye
```

It is harder to guess the intent of the calendar example.

```
\def\@testOccidental#1 #2, #3{
```

defines a command that takes three arguments, the first delimited by a space, the second by a comma and space and the third being an un-delimited `{..}` argument.

You only use this in one place, as `\@testOccidental\subject`  where there is just a single token and no space or comma delimiters. `\subject` is defined by `\def\subject{\today}`  so `\ifx\subject\month` is always going to be false, (and `\month` is a bad name for the loop variable as it is a TeX primitive for the current month number)

Trying to guess the intention of the loop over the months, perhaps something like:

[image]

```
\catcode`\@=11

\def\@pointer{\@pointer}
\long\def\@iterate#1#2#3,{%
    \def\cell{#3}%
    \ifx\cell\@pointer
        \let\next=\relax
    \else
        \def#1{#3}%
        #2%
        \def\next{\@iterate{#1}{#2}}%
    \fi
    \next
}



\long\gdef\foreach#1in#2#3%
{\@iterate{#1}{#3}#2,\@pointer,}

X\foreach \z in {a,b,c,d}{[\z]}X






\def\@testOccidental#1 #2, #3\relax{%
    \def\subject{#1}%
    \foreach \xmonth in {January,February,March,April,May,June,July,August,October,September,November,December}{%
        \ifx\subject\xmonth
            #1 #2, #3 (Occidental Solar)\par
        \else
             not \xmonth\par % just for debugging
        \fi
    }%
}
\def\checkCalendar#1{%
    \@testOccidental#1\relax
}

\checkCalendar{June 7, 2019}

\bye
```

Comment: Not my intention to limit the answer, but I want to share my progress with one way. 
So other than a few whitespace errors, the code only failed due to `\month` turning out a TeX primitive.

Of course, I'd appreciate knowing about more ways to write a parser in TeX.

Comment: What purpose might `\relax` serve in the code?

Comment: @Anonymouse `\relax` is a non expandable tex primitive that does nothing, I'm using it mostly just to delimit arguments here