# Turn string into macro (change catcodes)

Tags: strings, patching

Is it impossible to covert string back into macro? I know that with `lualatex` we can do a lot of funny things with macros. I have never seen string converting without it.

```latex
\documentclass{article}                                  
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}                              
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}                                 
\usepackage{tikz}                                        

\newcommand{\dosthfunny}{\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {\x\\}}

\def\Macro{\dosthfunny}                                  

\makeatletter                                            
\edef\String{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\Macro}    
\makeatother                                             

\begin{document}                                         
\String %change it to \dosthfunny macro                                                 
\end{document}
```

Comment: \scantokens does what you need

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1|21.9964

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not very clear what's the reason for this indirect method. You can use `\scantokens`:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand{\dosthfunny}{\foreach \x in {1,...,5} {\x\\}}

\def\Macro{\dosthfunny}

\makeatletter
\edef\String{\expandafter\strip@prefix\meaning\Macro}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\noindent
\scantokens\expandafter{\String} %change it to \dosthfunny macro

\end{document}
```

[image]