# How convert "string" into parameter?

Tags: luatex, parameters

How using `\myfunction{"TEST"}` to `\mysuperfunction{T}{E}{S}{T}`
I alvays have this same number of parameter

Comment: please clarify your question, what input do you want and what effect do you want to happen?

Comment: Welcome. As it stands the question is very unclear. Can you please add some more details?

Comment: very simple. I have one string but i need 2 parameter in my function I  wouldn't write {A}{B} but need write only one parameter {AB}. Shotrage my tex file

Comment: You might find https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1|39.7576 useful.

Comment: in your comment the string goes from AB to a two parameter command, in the question the example is completely different starting from a `"`-delimited argument with 4 letters (so 6 in total) going to a 4 parameter command. which do you want, the answers would be completely different.

Comment: i need in my tex file wrote \funkcja{TEST} and defining my function \newcommand[4]{{\it #1 \tt #2 \bf #3 \it #4}}  i need write one string but get 4 parameter similar chars

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436/4301).  Instead of describing what you want and then having to include comments to clarify, It is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228/4301) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it. Or at least provide as complete as possible test case.

Comment: so please edit your question to say that, currently it asks about an input with `"` which is a completely different form Note also that `\it` , `\bf` haven't been defined by default in LaTex since 1993, I assume you want `\textit{#1} \texttt{#2}`...

Answer (score 1):

Here is a possibility (if I understood the need correctly...):

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mysuperfunction#1#2#3#4{{\it#1\tt#2\bf#3\it#4}}
\newcommand\myfunction[1]{\mysuperfunction#1}

\begin{document}
\myfunction{TESTwithlontext}
\end{document}
```

And a solution without deprecated commands:

```
\documentclass{article}

\def\mysuperfunction#1#2#3#4{{\textit{#1}\texttt{#2}\textbf{#3}\textit{#4}}}
\newcommand\myfunction[1]{\mysuperfunction#1}

\begin{document}
\myfunction{TESTwithlontext}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Usual warning: the commands `\it` `\tt` `\bf` have been deprecated for 30 years

Answer (score 0):

Please always provide an example document as here, this answers the question as asked in the comments, the version in your question has `"` in the input which would complicate the answer slightly

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand\cmdA[4]{\textit{#1} \texttt{#2} \textbf{#3} \textit{#4}}
\newcommand\cmdB[1]{\cmdA#1}

\begin{document}

TEST

\cmdA{T}{E}{S}{T}

\cmdB{TEST}


\end{document}
```