# How to use macro argument as a comma-separated words for filtering

Tags: macros, filter

So I have this list of `\entry` macro that takes one argument which is simply a text.

```
\entry{whatevercoutent}
```

I want to make use of the second argument as a comma-separated list of words which would be used for filtering entries.

For example,

```
Some way to declare to only filter "filter1"

\entry{content1}{filter1, filter2, filter3}
\entry{content2}{filter1}
\entry{content3}{filter3}
```

In the example above, we declared that we would filter `filter1`. This would result in only content1 and content2 are rendered.

Is there a way to achieve this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The question isn't clear. What does mean "content with filter words". Give an example.

Comment: I'll try to be more clear. So currently I have this macro called `\entry` that takes a text to rendered as a first argument. I want to use the second argument as a comma-separated list of words where each word will be used to filter what entries are rendered and what are not.

So suppose that we declared that we filter "coffee". Then entries with second argument containing coffee will be rendered and others not containing coffee will be excluded.

Is this more understandable? Thanks a lot.

Comment: There are the xstring and pgfkeys packages.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1|39.3273 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's the idea: each “filter” defines a new sequence where to store entries. At the end you can use those sequences. I also define a global sequence to store all entries.

```
\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\entry}{mo}
 {% #1 is an entry, #2 is a list of filters (optional)
  \egreg_filterentry:nn { #1 } { #2 }
 }

\NewDocumentCommand{\printentries}{o}
 {
  \seq_use:cn { g__egreg_filterentry_ \IfNoValueTF { #1 } { global } { filter_#1 } _seq } {,~}
 }

\seq_new:N \g__egreg_filterentry_global_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \egreg_filterentry:nn
 {
  % store the entry in the global list
  \seq_gput_right:Nn \g__egreg_filterentry_global_seq { #1 }
  \tl_if_novalue:nF { #2 }
   {% we have a list of filters
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #2 }
     {% add the entry to the list corresponding to each given filter
      \__egreg_filterentry_filter:nn { #1 } { ##1 }
     }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__egreg_filterentry_filter:nn
 {%
  \seq_if_exist:cF { g__egreg_filterentry_filter_#2_seq }
   {% create the list if not yet existing
    \seq_new:c { g__egreg_filterentry_filter_#2_seq }
   }
  \seq_gput_right:cn { g__egreg_filterentry_filter_#2_seq } { #1 }
 }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\entry{content0}
\entry{content1}[filter1, filter2, filter3]
\entry{content2}[filter1]
\entry{content3}[filter3]

Global list: \printentries

filter 1: \printentries[filter1]

filter 2: \printentries[filter2]

filter 3: \printentries[filter3]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Wow this is amazing. Thanks a lot! I'm having some trouble modifying this to a form `\entry{content1}{subcontent}[filter1, filter2, filter3]`.  Also, what does `##1` mean?(sorry for asking about the basics) I know that `#1` means the first argument but I can't figure out what double # means.

Comment: @user10469929 It's hard to guess what the “subcontent” is for and what you want to achieve at the end of the day. Anyway, in the second argument to `\clist_map_inline:nn`, one uses `#1` to denote the current item in the loop; since we're using `\clist_map_inline:nn` inside a definition, one needs to double the number of `#` tokens, so in this case it becomes `##1`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. For the macro, this is the exact entry macro that I'm using (https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/197140/257356).  I want to translate this macro to `\entry{1982}{Knuth releases dvitype, a model DVI driver.}[filter1, filter2]` something like this.

Answer (score 1):

The task solved by egreg can be done without expl3:

```
\newcount\entrynum
\def\entries{}
\def\entry#1[#2]{\advance\entrynum by1
   \expandafter\entryA \expandafter{\the\entrynum}{#1}%
   \sdef{e:\the\entrynum:}{}%
   \entryB #2,\end,}
\def\entryA #1#2{\addto\entries{\tryprint{#1}{#2}}}
\def\entryB #1#2,{\ifx\end#1\else \sdef{e:\the\entrynum:#1#2}{}\expandafter\entryB\fi}

\def\sdef#1{\expandafter\def\csname#1\endcsname}
\def\addto#1#2{\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1#2}}

\def\tryprint#1#2{\ifcsname e:#1:\filter\endcsname \maybecomma #2\fi}
\def\printentries[#1]{\def\maybecomma{\def\maybecomma{, }}\def\filter{#1}\entries}

\entry{content1}[filter1, filter2, filter3]
\entry{content2}[filter1]
\entry{content3}[filter3]

Global list: \printentries[]

filter 1: \printentries[filter1]

filter 2: \printentries[filter2]

filter 3: \printentries[filter3]

\bye
```

The question given by OP is unclear.