# How to define a command that goes through all single letters in the parameter?

Tags: macros

I'd like to define a command that functions like:

```tex
\def\foo#1{...}   % function over single letters (e.g. making upper cases)
\def\bar#1{...}   % function over a paragraph by replacing each single letter with \foo
```

How can I reach this purpose?

Comment: Is this a TeX question? That is, are you interested in leaning how to achieve this using plain TeX?

Comment: Yes. I want to define the macro `\bar`, but I don't know how.

Comment: I've posted my own solution I've just found out. Any other ideas are welcomed.

Comment: What is meant by "go through all single letters in the parameter"? Does the macro argument contain tokens other than what you consider letters so that distinguishing letters from whatsoever non-letters is needed? What is meant by letters - just a-z and A-Z? How to handle `\letterA` after `\let\letterA=A`? How to handle expandable tokens where expansion at some point might deliver letters? Might multibyte-utf-8-characters on a traditional 8-bit-TeX-engine be an issue? || You might be interested in [l3regex](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/latex/contrib/l3kernel/interface3.pdf#chapter.8).

Comment: See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C39.4642  Paragraphs are tricky.  They can end with a blank line, a \par, a } or \end{...}. The only reliable method is `\everypar`, which runs at the begining of the next paragraph.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the following codes work:

```latex
\def\bar<#1#2>{\foo{#1}\if&#2&\else\bar<#2>\fi}
```

And `\bar<Hello>` will obtain `HELLO` if we define `\def\foo\uppercase`.

However, this cannot read spaces. `\bar<Hello World>` will obtain `HELLOWORLD`.