How to pass an argument to a macro called with \csname
I have a macro that generates lists of random numbers and converts them into letters to print. I'd like to create another macro that prints those lists with intervening text. That is, if
\first generates A, C, B, D,
then
\first{2} returns a C
and the functionality I'd like is something like:
sometext containing A, sometext containing C, sometext containing B, sometext containing D
The sometext containing may have the letter in the middle, and may be different depending on context. I'm using an X as a placeholder and using StrSubstitute to place the appropriate letter. This is not working, but I suspect it has more to do with the fact that one of the arguments comes from a foreach index using pgffor
My current working code   (with what I want commented out, since it doesn't work):
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\def\colors{4}
\def\version{2}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[first = 1, last = \colors, seed = \version]{lcg}

\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\newcommand{\row}{\item[Round \theenumi:] \stepcounter{enumi}}
\newcommand{\rn}{\rand\Alph{rand}}

\newcommand{\nums}[3]{\chgrand[counter = rand, seed = #2]
\foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{\ifnum\numexpr #3=0\rn~\else\ifnum\i=\numexpr #3\rn\else\makebox[0pt]{{\transparent{0}\rn}}\fi\fi}
}
\newcommand{\first}[1]{\nums{5}{\version}{#1}}

\newcommand{\expand}[3]{
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#2}{
        \StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{\i} %Code that works, but doesn't do what I want
%       \StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{\expandafter{\csname #3\endcsname{\i}}} %Code that I want, but doesn't work
    }
}

\newcommand{\dcinc}[2]{#1 text [#2] more text}

\begin{document}


\begin{description}
    \row \expand{\dcinc{3}{M,2 X},}{5}{first}
\end{description}
\end{document}```


You should be able to use \first and \first[2] (optional argument) but not \first{2}.  See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/233085/basics-of-parsing?r=SearchResults&s=1%7C40.6925

Welcome! Although you could define \first to take an optional argument in curly brackets, please don't. This is non-standard syntax in LaTeX and shouldn't be used when designing new commands. (OK, I use it sometimes myself but only for highly specific commands where correcting the syntax would break a bunch of existing documents. I wouldn't use it for a new command.)

You have a randomising element going into \first, so I don't see how it can produce the result you say you want?

What is the transparency for? I can't figure out what the various bits of your code are trying to accomplish ....

My feeling is that you believe \first stores a list of letters. It doesn't.

@JohnKormylo I'm not certain I understand. I am actually able to use \first{2} in places. Is that incorrect? Judging from @cfr's response, I'm thinking so, but I don't know why.

@cfr The argument to \first isn't optional. Or are you saying that I shouldn't (although could) make it so?

@cfr The transparency was part of a hack so that when it prints just the one letter, I don't get a whole bunch of unnecessary whitespace. I'm absolutely open to other ways of doing that, but it was what I could find to help me quickly.

@egreg I may have been imprecise with my language (and also my understanding). \first generates a set of random letters. It's not really stored in \first, since it's a macro and not a variable, per se. I need the macro to a) generate a set of random letters, b) generate the same set every time I compile with the same seed, and c) allow me to select just one of those lists of numbers if asked. I think that's what \first currently does for me, if rather inelegantly.

@cfr \first has the same seed each time. I want to be able to vary the seed per document, but keep it consistent throughout the document itself.

If you leave off a required argument, it will grab the first macro name or letter following and use it for the argument.

On the one hand:
The command \nums internally uses \chgrand for performing assignments. \nums also does \pgffor which in turn isn't fully expandable either. Performing assignments and other non-expandable commands in turn means that the command \nums does not work out only by means of expansion.
On the other hand:
The command \nums is used within the body of \expand's \foreach-loop while with \foreach-loops the body is expanded via \edef without taking LaTeX's \protect-expansion-protection into account which in turn implies that with \foreach the body is expected either to work out by expansion or to be expansion-protected by means of the TeX-engine's \protected\def.
I suggest defining and using an expansion-protected command \expansionprotectednums which calls \nums:
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}
\def\colors{4}
\def\version{2}

\usepackage{xstring}
\usepackage{pgf}
\usepackage{pgffor}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{listofitems}
\usepackage{transparent}

\usepackage[first = 1, last = \colors, seed = \version]{lcg}

\setcounter{enumi}{1}
\newcommand{\row}{\item[Round \theenumi:] \stepcounter{enumi}}
\newcommand{\rn}{\rand\Alph{rand}}

\newcommand{\nums}[3]{%
  \chgrand[counter = rand, seed = #2]%%%
  \foreach \i in {1,...,#1}{%
    \ifnum\numexpr(#3)\relax=0 %
      \rn~%
    \else
      \ifnum\i=\numexpr(#3)\relax
        \rn
      \else
        \makebox[0pt]{{\transparent{0}\rn}}%
      \fi
    \fi
  }%%%
}
\makeatletter
\@ifdefinable\expansionprotectednums{%
  \protected\def\expansionprotectednums{\nums}%
}%
\makeatother
\newcommand{\first}[1]{\expansionprotectednums{5}{\version}{#1}}

\newcommand{\expand}[3]{%%%
    \foreach \i in {1,...,#2}{%%%
%        \StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{\i} %Code that works, but doesn't do what I want
       \StrSubstitute{#1}{X}{\csname #3\endcsname{\i}} %Code that I want, and seems to work
    }%%%
}

\newcommand{\dcinc}[2]{#1 text [#2] more text}

\begin{document}


\begin{description}
    \row \expand{\dcinc{3}{M,2 X},}{5}{first}
\end{description}
\end{document}



Clarifying question: Is there any way to know in general what commands are expandable and which are not, or is that a "dig into the documentation" sort of thing? I suppose I really need to figure out the implications of expandable vs nonexpandable, what protected even means in this context, and what the heck makeatletter does because I've avoided anything with that command like the plague. But that's my own problem.

@CBaker Or code, if the documentation doesn't say. When LaTeX reads a class or package file, it typically treats @ as a regular letter so it can be used in macro names, for example. When LaTeX reads a document, it typically treats @ as a non-letter so it cannot be used in macro names. \makeatletter switches into @-as-regular-letter mode. \makeatother switches into @-as-non-letter mode. That's all.

@CBaker As a rule of thumbs commands that are to do other things than just removing tokens from the token stream and probably adding tokens to the token stream are not fully expandable. E.g., a command that does typeset a \hbox or \vbox and where the typeset box is needed for the command itself to work out is not fully expandable as typesetting boxes is not expansion. E.g., a command that (as side effect) does assignments and where the assignment being carried out is needed for the command itself to work out is not fully expandable as doing an assignment is not doing expansion.

@CBaker In case ypu are interested I tried to explain TeX's different stages of processing in my answers to Define commands without the need for brackets and 'a^^Mb' isn't equivalent to 'ab'; instead throws pdftex into an extended mode.

@CBaker I just said: "As a rule of thumbs commands that are to do other things than just removing tokens from the token stream and probably adding tokens to the token stream are not fully expandable." So often you can, without studying code or documentation, already guess that the command is not expandable from the fact that the focus of the command is on s.th. that is not done in the stage of expansion. E.g., the focus of \chgrand is on assigning values to parameters within the current scope permanently while assignments are not done in the stage of expansion but in a subsequent stage..

@UlrichDiez Thanks for the additional information; I'll take a look at it!

It's rather hard to work out the intention of the code in the question but I suspect that you do not need any of the packages used.

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn
\seq_new:N\l_cb_seq
% start with a list of letters
\seq_set_from_clist:Nn \l_cb_seq {a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h,i,j,k,l,m,n,o,p,q,r,s,t,u,v,w,x,y,z}
\let\reseed\sys_gset_rand_seed:n
\def\shuffle{\seq_shuffle:N \l_cb_seq}
\def\nth{\seq_item:Nn \l_cb_seq}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\reseed{1234}
\shuffle

2nd=\nth{2}, 5th=\nth{5}

\shuffle

2nd=\nth{2}, 5th=\nth{5}

\end{document}

This initialises a sequence with a list of letters, it then shuffles them using a repeatable random shuffle which will give the same order each run as the seed is explicitly set. Two example items are then shown, the list is re-shuffled and  the same item numbers are selected, showing their new values.

After clarifiction in comments
this version builds a random list of length 10 of "A", "B", "C", "D"  currently just one list called a here. It provides access funtion to the nth item of that list as \nth{a}{4} and provides an iterator that will loop over the full list using the specified letter in the dupplied function.
It produces terminal output
list a is: D,C,B,A,D,C,A,A,D,B
item 2 of list a: C

and typesets

\documentclass{article}

\ExplSyntaxOn

% generate one random value from ABCD (1 is the position in the list, not used)
\cs_new:Npn \cb_rand_color:n #1 {\char_generate:nn{`A+\int_rand:nn{0}{3}}{11},}

% set up list "a"  as a list of length 10
\clist_new:N\l_cb_lista_clist
\clist_set:Ne \l_cb_lista_clist {
  \int_step_function:nnN {1} {10} \cb_rand_color:n
}

% seed for the random numbers
\let\reseed\sys_gset_rand_seed:n

%The #2 item from list #1
\def\nth#1#2{\clist_item:cn{l_cb_list#1_clist}{#2}}

% iterate pver the list
\def\printlist#1#2{\clist_map_inline:cn {l_cb_list#1_clist} {#2}}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\typeout{list a is: \UseName{l_cb_lista_clist}}

\typeout{item 2 of list a: \nth{a}{2}}

\begin{document}

\reseed{54321}% arbitrary fixed seed for repeateable results

\printlist{a}{text [M,2,#1] more text}

\end{document}


If I wanted to change the seed, where would I do that here? Could I loop through the sequence somehow to insert the number/letter into a repeated statement? I'm writing a crochet pattern that selects from 4 random colors and places them into a line like so: "dc M, dc B, dc M, dc C, dc M, dc A, dc M, dc A, " etc. where the instructions could be complex and M remains the same each time.

How I missed the \reseed I don't know. The other clarifications still stand, though.

@CBaker yes I showed starting with a list and  shuffling it but for your case it sounds like you don't need a list of random numbers at all, just generate a new random number between 1 and 4 each time you need a color. why do you need a random list and access the nth item?  it seems you just want repeated calls to \int_rand:nn{1}[4}  to get col1, col2, col3, col4 which you can define as your colours.

I need to be able to access multiple lists of random numbers at the same time (I left that out as it wasn't necessary to my MWE). But I have also lists \second and \third and so on that also should be random from the same four colors and static for a given document.

@CBaker updated answer
