# How to mark the space between words

Tags: spacing, color, microtype

I would like to make the space between words of a text "more visible". 
Is there a way to colorize the word-space in a text?

Comment: in classic tex you would need to make space active, (and add coloured leaders) which is OK in controlled environments but is hard to make safe in a general context so it depends where you want this colour. In luatex you could colour the node list after typesetting so there are more possibilities, if using luatex is an option.

Comment: With luatex you could look at https://ctan.org/pkg/lua-visual-debug.

Comment: Somewhat related: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/232990/two-coloured-hyphenation

Comment: Hm, lua is a good hint but I'm affraid I get lost on the lua-visual-debug.lua code... I was looking for a way to fill the space between the words with colored rectangles with x-height. Should have been more specific I think.